# Make clean install of Ubuntu 20.04/Windows image it and deploy to 10 computers

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-20.04, disk-cloning

I am currently working on new project, where I have to install a clean system (Ubuntu 20/ Windows 10). Install all needed software, make and image of these system (Ubuntu and Windows), then deploy on few other computer (10 to 15 computers). The computer hardware are almost the same. I know there a different tools for Ubuntu and Windows.

But I need some hint for this project.

Comment: Where exactly in the process are you stuck?  How you image multiple machines is an extremely broad topic.  There is multiple ways to achieve that goal.

Comment: [Cloning](https://www.connectingup.org/learn/articles/cloning-fast-easy-way-set-up-multiple-computers) might be a good way to set up multiple PCs you could try that if possible of course